# Using Regex to insert sequence numbering

Tags: c#, regex

Currently (using C#) I'm using string methods **Instr**, **Substring** and **Insert** to place section numbers into a string. Even though the method works ok, it is very messy and not very manageable should I need to extend it as there's other stuff going on in the background. 
I was wondering if it's possible to use Regex to insert section numbers instead of using the standard string methods? If so, how is it done?

for example:

**Original String**

> The quick red fox. Jumped over the lazy dog? The quick red fox!
>   "Jumped over" the lazy dog.

**Output if using Regex**

> 1) The quick red fox. 2) Jumped over the lazy dog? 3) The quick red
>   fox! "4) Jumped over" the lazy dog.

PS: Here's the current method I'm using without Regex:

```
public string[] ApplyContentNumbering(string[] lines)
{
    int count = 1;
    if (lines != null && lines.Length > 0)
    {
        lines[0] = String.Format("{0} {1}", Chapter, lines[0].Substring(0));
        bool isOpen = false;

        for (int index = 1; index < lines.Length; index++)
        {
            count++;
            lines[index] = String.Format("{0} {1}", count, lines[index].Substring(0));

            if (lines[index].IndexOf("\"") > 0)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < lines[index].Length; c++)
                {
                    if (lines[index].Substring(c, 1).Equals("\""))
                    {
                        if (isOpen == false)
                        {
                            count++;
                            lines[index] = lines[index].Insert(c + 1, String.Format("{0}", count));
                            isOpen = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            isOpen = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the requirements? When to insert the numbers?

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I want to add numbering at the start of each sentence and at the start of each speech mark, so the sequence number is constantly incrementing.

Comment: I'm not sure a regex is the right approach for this. I believe the code could benefit from some refactoring because I can't tell how it is working at a quick glance. Separate some of the functionality out into methods that are independent from this specific method. Such as a method to break a line up into sentences. And then another method that takes inserts the sequence, etc.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5e%7c%5cp%7bP%7d%29%5cs%2b%28%22%3f%5cp%7bLu%7d%29&i=The+quick+red+fox.+Jumped+over+the+lazy+dog%3f+The+quick+red+fox!+%22Jumped+over%22+the+lazy+dog.&r=%241+N%29+%242) - are `N)` at the right places?

Comment: Yep N) looks correct and the highlighted text segments are also correct. I'm not sure how the numbering would be incremented? Would I need to do a foreach through all matches and manually increase numbering? I think that might be the best bet?

Comment: Adding numbering is easy. I see that my regex did not match the start of string, let me adjust it a bit.

Comment: You can't really parse language for sentence structure using regex. You could use the best guess and break up the sentences, then recombine. `\s*([^\pL\pN]*[\pL\pN](?:[\pL\pN_-]|\pP(?=[\pL\pN\pP_-])|[?.!])*)` This lets you see the  _possible_ sentence structure in a more atomic way.

Comment: Hi sln, yes you're right. In my original method, I was splitting the string using regex at all punctuation marks and then using my old method (displayed in the question) for applying the numbering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use an *approximate* (or "good-enough") approach here that will consist in adding the incrementing numbers at the start of string/after punctuation and 1+ whitespaces followed with an uppercase letter.

Here is a [C# demo](http://ideone.com/wj8ZjF):

```
var pat = @"(^|\p{P}\s+)(""?\p{Lu})";
var s = "The quick red fox. Jumped over the lazy dog? The quick red fox! \"Jumped over\" the lazy dog.";
var cnt = 0;
var res = Regex.Replace(s, pat, m =>
        string.Format("{0}{1}) {2}", m.Groups[1].Value, ++cnt, m.Groups[2].Value));
Console.WriteLine(res);
// => 1) The quick red fox. 2) Jumped over the lazy dog? 3) The quick red fox! 4) "Jumped over" the lazy dog.
```

The regex - [`(^|\p{P}\s+)("?\p{Lu})`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5E%7C%5Cp%7BP%7D%5Cs%2B%29%28%22%3F%5Cp%7BLu%7D%29&i=The%20quick%20red%20fox.%20Jumped%20over%20the%20lazy%20dog%3F%20The%20quick%20red%20fox!%20%22Jumped%20over%22%20the%20lazy%20dog.&r=%241N%29%20%242) - matches:

- `(^|\p{P}\s+)`  -  Group 1 capturing start of string or punctuation symbol and 1+ whitespaces
- `("?\p{Lu})` - Group 2 capturing an optional `"` and then an uppercase letter.

To actually split texts into sentences in a more reliable way, you'd better use some NLP package.

Comment: Ah, you're using linq to do the replace, that's nifty! I never thought you could do that. Thank you!